# JVM is crashing randomly when trying to use Eclipse

Tags: 10.04, java, eclipse

Since I installed Ubuntu 10.04 on my PC, I have eclipse crashing every hour or more without apparent action.
In the logs, I see that the cause is related to JAVA :

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f95f32ce9c0, pid=2382, tid=140280562099984
#
# JRE version: 6.0_18-b18
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (16.0-b13 mixed mode linux-amd64 )
# Derivative: IcedTea6 1.8.2
# Distribution: Ubuntu 10.04.1 LTS, package 6b18-1.8.2-4ubuntu2
# Problematic frame:
# V  [libjvm.so+0x5309c0]
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /home/elapouya/perso/projects/django/rsame/hs_err_pid2382.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please include
# instructions how to reproduce the bug and visit:
#   https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openjdk-6/
#
```

www.eclipse.org knows this bug and it is RECOMMENDED to use 1.6.0.10 or more, or go jdk 1.5
I installed the latest JVM official but still crashes. I 6.0_18-b18 (I do not know if this is 1.6.0.10 ...)
So I installed an older version: 1.5.0_19, but I still have random crashes:

```
#
# An unexpected error has been detected by HotSpot Virtual Machine:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007fc833c91dfe, pid=8630, tid=140496587896592
#
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (1.5.0_19-b02 mixed mode)
# Problematic frame:
# V  [libjvm.so+0x5b1dfe]
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as hs_err_pid8630.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport/crash.jsp
#
```

I did an apt-get upgrade to be up-to-date, but it continues to crash:

What do you recommend?

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, thanks! [Instructions here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Answer (score 1):

I would switch to the 32-bit jre/jdk and file a bug report...once they sort it out back to 64-bit.  Alternately, you could try the binary installer from Sun directly instead of the openjdk, but this may mess with your dependencies and you'll have to set some environment variables in .profile or .bashrc

Comment: note: I used to get weird crashes from openjdk x64 and was forced to switch to Sun to fix it.

Comment: secondary note: i do not plan on switching back...it's one of the libraries i deal with on my own. others include most of multimedia, voip, ruby, gems, and almost ALL security tools.  i mount /opt over the network and have an x64 and i386 partitions, that way i can do compiles once and use them on a bunch of installs.  there are some areas where ubuntu fails, possibly due to policy or licensing restrictions.  i disagree with the gem vs apt contest that debian derived is having, but they still have the best hands-off install.  i can tweak the rest of it

Comment: how can I install a 32bit jre/jdk on a 64Bits ubuntu version ?

Comment: update-alternatives there's a gui front-end g or kalternative depending on your desktop(gnome/kde).  they are available through synaptic

Comment: I tried the latest 32bits version from Sun, but crashes still occurs with the same symptomes (SIGSEGV in libjvm.so)

Comment: is it crashing with a specific application running?  if it does this with multiple versions of the jvm and other's haven't reported the bug...i would think it's probably application dependent